# Combine two list with equal element names into list of lists by element name R

Tags: r

I have two lists, one with matrices and one with vectors. Both have named elements which are equal. This looks like this:

```
set.seed(1)
mat_list <- list("2009" = matrix(runif(n = 9, min = 0, max = 10), 3, 3),
                 "2010" = matrix(runif(n = 9, min = 0, max = 10), 3, 3))
vec_list <- list("2009" = c(runif(n = 3, min = 0, max = 10)),
                 "2010" = c(runif(n = 3, min = 0, max = 10)))
```

What I want is to create a new list with the elements `2009` and `2010` that contains the respective matrix and vector, so that I can acces them both in a `lapply` call. My actual dat has some more years, so I would be nice to not have to reference the years explicitly.

I found a bunch of similar questions, but I couldn't figure out how to apply the answers to my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `purrr` package and the `map2` function, you can do this:

```
#install_packages("purrr")
set.seed(1)
mat_list <- list("2009" = matrix(runif(n = 9, min = 0, max = 10), 3, 3),
                 "2010" = matrix(runif(n = 9, min = 0, max = 10), 3, 3))
vec_list <- list("2009" = c(runif(n = 3, min = 0, max = 10)),
                 "2010" = c(runif(n = 3, min = 0, max = 10)))

l <- purrr::map2(mat_list, vec_list, function(x,y) list(x,y))
#l <- purrr::map2(mat_list, vec_list, ~list(.x,.y)) #shorter notation
#l <- purrr::map2(mat_list, vec_list, list) #even shorter

#x and y inside the map2 are the elements of each list at each iteration, 
#so we can combine them in a list
```

Thanks to @markus:

```
l <- Map(list, mat_list, vec_list) # no need for another package
```

Comment: You could actually do `purrr::map2(mat_list, vec_list, list)` or without extra package `Map(list, mat_list, vec_list)`

Comment: Didn't know about `Map`. I used the longer version because I tend to find it more clear when people not used to `*apply/map` see it.